# Android 10 mediaplayer not working getting error stop called in state 1, mNative: error (-38, 0)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

My code working fine in all devices below android 10. But when app run in android 10 mediaplayer not working. here my code

```
mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mplayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(SongPathlocation)));
        mplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mplayer.prepare();

        mplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mplayer.start();

            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem lies in the SongPathLocation. From android 10 the full path of the audio file is not available. That`s why it's giving error.

Comment: Hello there, if there is a solution kindly answer it because I am facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to `AndroidManifest.xml` file, in application section this:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```